# GXT Grid translate

Tags: gwt, translation, gxt

i've tried to translate one of GXT widgets - Grid (exacly context menu in column header with sorting etc.) into Polish language but i cant find place to inject my translation.
In some other widget (PagingToolBar) is method setMessages(...) but i cant find it in Grid

So im asking you about place where i can set text that will be displayed in that menu.

Does anyone done this before ?

PS. Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this:

http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideI18nLocale.html

and put `<extend-property name="locale" values="pl_PL"/>` in your `module.gwt.xml` and `<meta name='gwt:property' content='locale=pl_PL'>` in your index.html.

This (imho) should be the right way.

P.S. I'm not sure, if the pl_PL is right:)

Answer (score 0):

...and [Javadoc about gxt XMessages](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/gxtdocs/com/extjs/gxt/ui/client/messages/XMessages.html#gridView_sortAscText%28%29) (message for sort asc) and google for "Missing in the Tutorial GXT and I18N inurl:sencha" (sorry i'm not allowed to post more than one link here)